# Phone Gap In APP Browser

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am adding the Phonegap in app browser because I have some links in my app and when they are launched using the iPhone you can't return to the app (a common problem I believe).

I have tried to add the in app browser but it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I have done.

Added a Config.xml to the root of the app. This is my Config.xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.phonegap.my.example"
    versionCode = "10"
    version     = "1.0.0" >

  <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

  <name>Testt App APP</name>

  <description>
    This is a test app.
  </description>

  <author href="http://www.mywebaddress.co.uk"          email="email@mywebaddress.co.uk">
    My Name
  </author>

  <gap:plugin name="org.li8.inappbrowser" version="0.1" />

</widget>
```

In the page with the link I have added the cordova.js ref

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Does this need to be in certain order (before or after Jquery ref). Do I need to include this file in my program or does phonegap automatically include it?

I have tried 2 types of link:

```
var ref = window.open('http://twitter.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

and

```
window.open('http://www.facebook.com', '_system');
```

Neither seem to work.

Am I missing somthing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best and easiest way is to install cordova with the command line: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface and after that install the inappbrowser from here: http://node-modules.com/search?u=&q=ecosystem%3Acordova+inappbrowser and don't change files, if you don't know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to do it through the pphone gap web interface?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Phonegap.

Comment: Ok thanks. Looking at the cordova installation guide it would appear that you can only build for ios using a mac. I only have a windows machine.

Comment: That's right, but in Phonegap you never have the newest cordova, plugins and you have less capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Ok managed to solve it.

I noticed that none of the plugins tab wasn't showing any installed plugins. So I deleted the config.xml and stated again. The plugin then showed up and it works ok now. The only difference I can see it that I renamed the config file config.xml as opposed to Config.xml.